# Out of Memory Exception When Using HttpWebRequest to Stream Large File

Tags: c#, streaming, out-of-memory

I get an Out of Memory Exception when using Http.Put of a large file. I am using an asynchronous model as shown in the code. I am trying to send 8K blocks of data to a Windows 2008 R2 server. The exception consistently occurs when I attempt to write a block of data that exceeds 536,868,864 bytes. The exception occurs on the requestStream.Write method in the code snippet below.

Looking for reasons why?

Note: Smaller files are PUT OK. Logic also works if I write to a local FileStream. Running VS 2010, .Net 4.0 on Win 7 Ultimate client computer.

```
   HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("Http://website/FileServer/filename");
   request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Put;
   request.SendChunked = true;
   request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
   ...

   request.BeginGetRequestStream( new AsyncCallback(EndGetStreamCallback), state);
   ...

   int chunk = 8192; // other values give same result
   ....

   private static void EndGetStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
        long limit = 0;
        long fileLength;
        HttpState state = (HttpState)ar.AsyncState;

        Stream requestStream = null;
        // End the asynchronous call to get the request stream.

        try {
            requestStream = state.Request.EndGetRequestStream(ar);
            // Copy the file contents to the request stream.

            FileStream stream = new FileStream(state.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, chunk, FileOptions.SequentialScan);

            BinaryReader binReader = new BinaryReader(stream);
            fileLength = stream.Length;

            // Set Position to the beginning of the stream.
            binReader.BaseStream.Position = 0;

            byte[] fileContents = new byte[chunk];

            // Read File from Buffer 
            while (limit < fileLength)
            {
                fileContents = binReader.ReadBytes(chunk);

                // the next 2 lines attempt to write to network and server
                requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, chunk);   // causes Out of memory after 536,868,864 bytes
                requestStream.Flush();  // I get same result with or without Flush

                limit += chunk;
            }

            // IMPORTANT: Close the request stream before sending the request.
            stream.Close();

            requestStream.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the same happen with POST? Does your code actually send any data?

Comment: You may want to look into .NET 4's new `CopyTo()` method for streams

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You apparently have [this documented problem](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/908573). When `AllowWriteStreamBuffering` is `true`, it buffers *all the data written to the request*! So, the "solution" is to set that property to `false`:

> To work around this issue, set the HttpWebRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering property to false.

Comment: It's also mentioned in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowwritestreambuffering.aspx): “Setting AllowWriteStreamBuffering to true might cause performance problems when uploading large datasets because the data buffer could use all available memory.”

Comment: Yes, we tried this and continue to have challenges with either setting that to true or false.  I expect that the real solution is to not use PUT or POST to do updates, but instead use a more low level technology like WCF or POS (Plain Ole Sockets lol).

Comment: @pearcewg: Add an update to your question (or your own answer!) if you figure out a sure-fire way of getting it to work -- I'm curious too, and it'd be good to have a reference to refer to in the future ;-)

Comment: we ended up dumping this, and replaced it with uploading via WCF, which works just great!  I would recommend looking at the same solution.

Comment: @pearcewg: Cool, good to know. Thanks! What class did you use?

Comment: Brilliant answer. I managed to upload 600M file from a 512M RAM device running on Xamarin Forms. Without the setting it was crashing at around 20% upload.