# Powershell 3: preventing excessive memory usage for webrequest

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I wrote a short script that lets me download a file.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $r2.Forms.Action -WebSession $myWebSession -OutFile $destination$filename
```

The whole download is buffered in memory, which is obviously not optimal for larger files. I was wondering (and I couldnt find) a way/ property to prevent this and stream straight to disk. Something along the lines of AllowWriteStreamBuffering in .NET.

[Out of Memory Exception When Using HttpWebRequest to Stream Large File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247040/out-of-memory-exception-when-using-httpwebrequest-to-stream-large-file)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems the only way to do this is using WebClient

```
$webclient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($id, $p, $url)
$webclient.DownloadFile($r2, $destination+$tempfile)

#rename tempfile
$filename = $webclient.ResponseHeaders["Content-Disposition"].SubString($webclient.ResponseHeaders["Content-Disposition"].IndexOf("filename=")+10).Replace("`"", "");
Rename-Item $destination$tempfile -NewName $filename
```